# Regex to find alphanumeric patterns in a string

Tags: python, regex

I have the regex to find an alphanumeric of length 6 in a string. The string is something like below:

```
PLT\n\nTRAVELLER NAME LIST\n\n     TRAVELLER              RECLOC COMPANY\n   1          TESTNUMBERFIVEQA/TESTN WL9795\n   2 TESTNUMBERONEYQWA/TEST RHFQCD\n   3 TESTNUMBERONEYQWAZZZ/T 1QZ1JF\n   4 TESTNUMBERONEYQWAZZZM/ N3BZW8\n   5 TESTNUMBERONEYQWAZZZMK 05RXPM\n   6 TESTNUMBERONEYQWAZZZMK 2XR9ZR\n   7 TESTNUMBERTHREEZZZ/TES 0Q14S4\n   8 TESTNUMBERTHREEZZZM/TE LRRKW3\n   9 TESTNUMBERTHREEZZZMK/T 949Z4T\n  10 TESTNUMBERTHREEZZZMKJ/ 51WFM2\n  11 TESTNUMBERTWOZZA/TESTN PRGWVT\n  12 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZ/TE SM0BHS\n  13 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZM/T QRJLH1\n  14 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMK/ R69NHV\n  15 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ 67XKF7\n  16 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ 68PV7P\n  17 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ GCZZ0C\n)>  18 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ MLMS3L\n  19 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ 3R1S49\n  20 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ WB700R\n  21 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ 718KRC\n  22 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ RTQH2H\n  23 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ N2FLM6\n  24 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ 40M1FR\n  25 TESTNUMBERTWOZZAZZZMKJ 71D3HF\n  26
```

And the regex I have tried is something like this:

```
for k in mainString:
    m = re.match('([0-9A-Z]{6})', k)
    if (m):
        do something
```

But its not working as expected. Can someone point out where i may be making a blunder?
The pattern i am looking for are like WL9795, RHFQCD, etc.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `match` method only checks for a match at the beginning of the string.

Use the `search` method instead!

Also, the `()` are unnecessary.

If `mainString` in your code is actually the string at the top of your question, then your code will not work correctly, as the `for` loop will iterate through all the individual characters in that string.

Instead you could use

```
m = re.search(r'\b[0-9A-Z]{6}\b', mainString)
if (m):
    print(m.group())
```

The `r` before the regex ensures that the `\b` is not treated as a string escape sequence.

The `\b` mean word boundary and ensure that the 6 character alphanumeric is not preceded or followed by a word character. Without them the first match would be the `"TRAVEL"` in `"TRAVELLER"`.

If you want to get a list of all the matches use `findall` or `finditer` instead of `search`.

```
for m in re.finditer(r'\b[0-9A-Z]{6}\b', mainString):
    print(m.group())
```

Comment: for k in mainString:
        m = re.search('[0-9A-Z]{6}', k)
        if (m):
            do something




Have something like above, but still no progress!

Comment: I got this error:

Runtime exception: argument 1 must be string or read-only character buffer, not _sre.SRE_Match

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that you might want some word boundaries in there:

```
>>> print re.findall(r'\b\w{6}\b',s)
['RECLOC', 'WL9795', 'RHFQCD', '1QZ1JF', 'N3BZW8', '05RXPM', '2XR9ZR', '0Q14S4', 'LRRKW3', '949Z4T', '51WFM2', 'PRGWVT', 'SM0BHS', 'QRJLH1', 'R69NHV', '67XKF7', '68PV7P', 'GCZZ0C', 'MLMS3L', '3R1S49', 'WB700R', '718KRC', 'RTQH2H', 'N2FLM6', '40M1FR', '71D3HF']
```

This regex matches alphanumeric patterns which are exactly characters long.  In other words, it doesn't match anything in `"foobarbaz"` but it will match `foobar` from `"foobar."`

Comment: re.findall(r'\b(\w{6})\b$',s,re.M) gets rid of the 'RECLOC' outlier.

Comment: this isn't the desired pattern I am looking for.
thanks for the effort.

Comment: @pyInTheSky I suppose that the `$` would make the last `\b` redundant since the end of a line would be a word boundary ... `re.findall(r'\b\w{6}$',s,re.M)`